# three.js animation layer mask

Tags: animation, three.js

I've been learning Playcanvas and on the examples, I see that I can achieve layer animation by masking the bones. My question is can I apply something similar on three.js?

this is the example:

https://playcanvas.github.io/#/animation/layer-masks

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is not supported in current `three.js` version (`r141`).

You can layer animations with via additive blending like demonstrated in the following example. However, the animations affect the entire skeleton and not specific bones.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending